# Retrieving Jquery object data

Tags: jquery

maybe getting a brain freeze there but i cannot get this to work. any help would be appreciated. thanks

```
var prlist = loadList(rootUrl + '?action=product&country_id=' + userSelCountry);

response from PHP : [{"id":"-1","text":"no results found"}]
```

I have tried the following with no success

```
console.log(prlist) //  [Object { id="-1",  text="no results found"}]
console.log(prlist.id);//undefined
console.log(prlist['id'] // undefined
```

I need to retrieve the id value.

thanks

Comment: Need to parse the json

Comment: check this http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

Comment: The response is already parsed. `prlist` is an array! Arrays don't have `id` properties.

Comment: @DevendraBhandari an unparsed string can't log `Object` within the array